# How do you avoid a string containing a "null" value?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm new with AMPscript, and I believe my question is going to be easy to answer. I'm trying to avoid table cell from a DE that has "null" text field to be printed into the `<td></td>`. It actually should print a blank space within the `<td></td>`. I have read and tried few different approaches. Also, I'm trying to understand If `IsNull()` function will work with my concept.

```
elseif empty(@lookup) then
set @lookup = ""
```

or

```
else 
   set @promocode = ""
   set @banner = ""
```

maybe

```
IsNull()
```

Here is the code:

```
<table>

  %%[ 

  var @lookup, @offer,@offerrow, @promocode, @banner 

  set @offer = [Offer]

  set @lookup = Lookuprows("DE", "Offer", @offer)

  if RowCount(@lookup) > 0 then
     set @offerrow = Row(@lookup,1)
     set @promocode = Field(@offerrow,"PromoCode")
     set @banner = Field(@offerrow, "BannerURL")     
  endif 

  ]%%

  <tr>
    <td>%%=v(@promocode)=%%</td>
    <td>%%=v(@banner)=%%></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good practice to not just check for the empty result values, but also upstream from there.

```
%%[ 

var @lookup, @offer,@offerrow, @promocode, @banner 
set @offer = AttributeValue("Offer")

if not empty(@offer) then

    set @lookup = Lookuprows("DE", "Offer", @offer)

    if RowCount(@lookup) > 0 then
        set @offerrow = Row(@lookup,1)
        set @promocode = Field(@offerrow,"PromoCode")
        set @banner = Field(@offerrow, "BannerURL") 
        set @promocode = iif(trim(@promocode) == "null","",@promocode)
        set @banner = iif(trim(@banner) == "null","",@banner)   
    endif 

    ]%%

    %%[ if not empty(@banner) or not empty(@promocode) then ]%%

    <table>
        <tr>

        %%[ if not empty(@promocode) then ]%%

            <td>%%=v(@promocode)=%%</td>

        %%[ endif ]%%

        %%[ if not empty(@banner) then ]%%

            <td>%%=v(@banner)=%%></td>

        %%[ endif ]%%

        </tr>
    </table>

    %%[ endif ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

<br>offer not found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Thanks, Adam! I feel I have 1000 questions for you! What do you mean by Upstream? Also, Is it important to close with so many endif? I saw a lot of people write a loop @i for this similar promotion... Is it necessary?

Comment: Upstream meaning, checking to make sure you are returning rows before you output your table (`if not empty(@offer) then`).  No need to loop if you're only returning a single row in your lookup.  I have some examples on my blog: [AMPScript Lookup Examples](https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out your blog to learn more. However, I still see the "null" into the email? some of my rows don't have URL for the bannerurl column or promocode into the promocode column. Instead, It's a "null" value. Can you avoid this null to be print? or you need to put a default text to replace this value field?(i can show you a screenshot? If you want.)

Comment: If "null" is a string, then you'll have to detect it.  Updated my answer above.

Comment: "+1" Perfect! I did look at the iif function, but I saw the function written with Concat... so I didn't fully understand how this function work...Thanks. I need to find a way to learn and understand more how certain function works. So I'll start to write better AMPscript codes.